# Scala guarded pattern with or matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to do a pattern match that looks like :

```
    sinceOp match {
        case  None |Some(lastUpdate) if lastUpdate<= update.time =>
```

Saddly this does not work. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could can also test the reverse condition:

```
sinceOp match {
  case Some(lastUpdate) if lastUpdate > update.time => //...
  case _ => //...
}
```

The second case covers both `None` and the case where the last update is smaller.

Comment: This is definitely the better solution!

Answer (score 3):

Or you can replace pattern matching with chain of functions

```
sinceOp.filterNot(_ <= update.time).getOrElse(println("if None"))
```